# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(-1)^nn+1}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(-1)^nn+1}=0$

I need a little tip on how I can deal with this problem.

**Edit**: The statement of the problem is missing that n should be greater than or equal to 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: Tip: It's false

Comment: As you probably already realized this is undefined for odd $n$. Also for even $n$ we clearly get $\frac{1}{2}$. So in any case this is an oscillating sequence. Please refine your question.

Comment: This is not a sequence.

Comment: Oops, I've written it wrong. I'll edit now.

Comment: for n = 1 the sequence is still not defined

Comment: Why I got so many downvotes? It's a problem from my problembook on real analysis. It must be a wrong problem.

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov You got downvoted because you did not show efforts at all to solve.

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov You copied the problem wrong at first. You should check carefully before you post your question.

Comment: @kingW3 That's why I said I needed a tip, so that I don't get a full solution. I had struggle with dealing with the varying sign of  n in the denominator. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*:

For $n\ge 2$,

$$\left|\frac1{(-1)^nn+1}\right|\le\frac1{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(-1)^nn+1}=0$$

There's a problem for $n=1$ so I'll assume $n > 1$. Note that for $n \ge 2$:
$$\frac{1}{1-n} \le \frac{1}{(-1)^nn+1} \le \frac{1}{1+n}$$
since $(-1)^n = -1$ for odd $n$ and $(-1)^n = 1$ for even $n$. Now use the squeeze theorem.